AzCopy download data (integrity check)
I'm using AzCopy(10.17.0) to upload/download data to Storage Account/File share. While uploading I'm using --put-md5 command and can see the Md5 hash in the storage account( Content-MD5 property) for the blob.
So while downloading, does AZCopy checks the hash by default or we specifically need to use --check-md5 flag in my AzCopy command in order to check the data integrity?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download
This document highlights the MD5 check but doesn't say that we need to explicitly use --check-md5 command.


So while downloading, does AZCopy checks the hash by default or we
specifically need to use --check-md5 flag in my AzCopy command in
order to check the data integrity?

This is what the documentation says:

If the Content-md5 property value of a blob contains a hash, AzCopy
calculates an MD5 hash for downloaded data and verifies that the MD5
hash stored in the blob's Content-md5 property matches the calculated
hash. If these values don't match, the download fails unless you
override this behavior by appending --check-md5=NoCheck or
--check-md5=LogOnly to the copy command.

The way I understand this is by defauly md5 checksum will be verified and the download will fail if the checksum doesn't match. You need to specify --check-md5 parameter only if you do not want to do this verification.
